# I misspelled my domayn name

Tags: code-golf, string

According to Alexa rankings, the top 10 websites are:

```
google.com
youtube.com
facebook.com
baidu.com
yahoo.com
wikipedia.org
amazon.com
twitter.com
qq.com
google.co.in
```

Being the top 10 visited websites, these are probably also the top 10 misspelled websites <sup>[Citation Needed]</sup>.

## Your task

Your goal is to write a program or function that accepts a string containing a misspelled domain name, and outputs all domain names on the top 10 list that are spelled similarly.

### Rules

- Each input may be up to three characters off from a correct website. A changed character may a substitution (cat -> cot), addition (cat -> cant), or removal (cat -> at).
- Moving a letter counts as two characters changed (the deletion of one character and the addition of another)
- The input will only include the characters a-z, period, and dash
- The name of a website does not include the `http(s)://` or the `www.` The websites are exactly as listed above.
- The program must print out all websites that match the input.
- Case doesn't matter. The test cases will be presented as lower case, but if your program requires upper case, that's fine too.
- As always, no standard loopholes.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Some test cases

(Input followed by outputs)

```
yahoo.com
yahoo.com (no change for correct spelling)

goggle.com
google.com

wikipedia.organ
wikipedia.org

bidua.cm
baidu.com

.om
qq.com

google.co.i
google.com and google.co.in

google.com
google.com and google.co.in

twipper.com
twitter.com

yahoo.org
yahoo.com

amazing.com
amazon.com

factbook.co
facebook.com

ki-pedia.org
wikipedia.org

google.co.india
google.co.in

goo.com
google.com

aol.com
qq.com

qqzon.com
qq.com and amazon.com
```

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=87174,OVERRIDE_USER=41505;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I think "outputs the correct version" would be clearer if it said that every possible correct version must be output, as the rules later say.

Comment: @xnor How's this? I also added some corner cases to the test suite.

Comment: Looks good. Are the inputs limited to printable ASCII? In particular, can there be spaces or newlines?

Comment: @xnor Good point; I'll clarify that

Comment: @xnor The input will only include the characters a-z, period, and dash

Comment: Borderline dupe of [Levenshtein distance](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67474/194), since it's basically just using that as a filter predicate.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>167</s> 166 bytes

*Saved one byte thanks to Martin Ender*

```
iSelect[{"google.com","youtube.com","facebook.com","baidu.com","yahoo.com","wikipedia.org","amazon.com","twitter.com","qq.com","google.co.in"},#~EditDistance~i<4&]
```

Defines a pure function that returns a list of urls.

The `` is [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Function.html)

This answer uses the same method as my NodeJS answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <s>229</s> <s>205</s> <s>185</s> 174 bytes

```nim
import strutils,sequtils,future
s=>"googlexyoutubexfacebookxbaiduxyahooxwikipedia.org amazonxtwitterxqqxgoogle.co.in".replace("x",".com ").split.filterIt it.editDistance(s)<4
```

Yep, Nim has a builtin for Levenshtein distance (although it requires an `import`), which is what the question described.

Defines an anonymous procedure, which must be passed to a testing procedure to be used. An testing program is provided below:

```nim
import strutils,sequtils,future
proc test(d: string -> seq[string]) = echo d #[Your input here]#
test(s=>"googlexyoutubexfacebookxbaiduxyahooxwikipedia.org amazonxtwitterxqqxgoogle.co.in".replace("x",".com ").split.filterIt it.editDistance(s)<4)
```

Comment: Woah, I haven't seen Nim in the wild in a while. That's awesome that it's still an active language.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I just discovered it. It's a good language for golfing (if you can use a lambda), what with the builtins and the number of ways to call a proc.

Comment: Nice! I played around with it a bit last year and really liked it, I never did any golfing with it though.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 240 bytes

```js
f=
s=>`google.com,youtube.com,facebook.com,baidu.com,yahoo.com,wikipedia.org,amazon.com,twitter.com,qq.com,google.co.in`.split`,`.filter(t=>[...s].map((u,i)=>(q=p=i+1,w=w.map((v,j)=>p=Math.min(++p,q-(u==t[j]),q=++v))),w=[...[...t].keys()])|p<4)
;
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value).join`\n`><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>216</s> <s>200</s> <s>193</s> 183 bytes

```
import editdistance as e
i=raw_input()
print[n for n in"googlexyoutubexfacebookxbaiduxyahooxamazonxtwitterxqqxgoogle.co.in wikipedia.org".replace('x','.com ').split()if e.eval(i,n)<4]
```

The module editdistance calculates the Levenshtein distance, which is the straightforward implementation of what the challenge was asking for.

EDIT: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @shooqie

EDIT 2: Saved another 10 bytes thanks to @shooqie and @Frank

Comment: `split()` (without the space character) does the same thing (at least in Python 3)

Comment: @shooqie Yup, that works, thanks. Moving the list inside of the print statement instead of declaring a variable saves a few bytes too.

Comment: You could save a few characters by writing "import editdistance as e" and then calling e.eval rather than writing editdistance again.

Comment: You can remove the space between `in` and `"googlexyoutube..."` and `split()` and `if` (again, it works in Python 3). Also, in Python 2 you can omit parentheses when calling `print`

Comment: One last thing: `print [...]` -> `print[...]` and I noticed you're only using `i` in one place, why not `e.eval(raw_input(),n)<4` then? Also, consider using `input()` instead of `raw_input()` since you only need a `str`.

Comment: @shooqie Huh. Completely missed that space after print. But for the other 2 things: `input()` in python 2 is the equivalent of `eval(input())` in python 3, which causes an error, since the input contains a period, so python tries to evaluate it as a function from a class. Also, you can't put the `raw_input()` inside of the print statement, due to the fact that the output is generated using list comprehension.

Comment: Oh yeah. I guess it makes sense, forgot about it. Anyway, looks like this can't be golfed down any further :)

Answer (score 2):

## NodeJS, <s>163</s> <s>161</s> 151 bytes

*10 bytes saved thanks to Copper's Nim solution*

```
x=>"google youtube facebook baidu yahoo wikipedia.org,amazon twitter qq google.co.in".replace(/ /g,".com,").split`,`.filter(y=>require("leven")(x,y)<4)
```

[Try it on Tonic](http://tonicdev.com/dinod123/nearesturl)

Defines an anonymous function that returns an array of urls.

This solution uses Levenshtein distance, which happens to be exactly what was described by the rules. This answer just selects the urls from an array based on if their Levenshtein distance is small enough.