# Create an auto-cucumber program

Tags: code-golf, string, substitution

> Oops, Auto-correct.

You have a word. But it's wrong. You wonder what word it would be. Thankfully, being a code golfer, You can make a code to take a rough guess.

## I/O

You will be given a (wrong, all lowercase) word, and a ['(All lowercase)Dictionary list'](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt). You have to output the word with the least Levenshtein distance to the wrong word. If there are multiple words of the same levenshtein distance, use the last one in the list.

## Examples

```
Input => Output
(["apple", "banana", "orange", "pineapple"], "baenanae") => "banana"
(["zeal", "zealot", "zealotry", "zealots", "zealous", "zealously", "zealousness"], "zealousl") => "zealously"
(["abductors", "abducts", "abe", "abeam", "abel"], "") => "abe"
```

Comment: Will the empty string ever be in either part of the input?

Comment: This is just a loop around https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67474/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor it appears so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
Σ.L(}¤
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3GI9H43aQ0v@/49Wr0pNzFHXUQDT@SUIVlElgl0MZ5YiM3MqkTh5qcXF6rFcMCkuAA)** (note: the trailing newline on the input is necessary for the empty string case.)

#### How?

```
Σ.L(}¤ - implicitly push the first input (the dictionary list)
Σ   }  - sort the list by:
       -   implicitly push second input (the misspelled word)
 .L    -   Levenshtein distance
   (   -   negated
     ¤ - tail the sorted list  and place the entry on the top of the stack
       - implicitly print top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 + [pylev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylev), 77 bytes

```
lambda m,s:min({levenshtein(x,s):x for x in m}.items())[1]
from pylev import*
```

[Try it on repl.it!](https://repl.it/KtUt/1)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[-1]`? Ah no my bad... what happens with multiple minima?

Comment: See my edit above - I assumed you wanted to get the rightmost (as per requirements) but noticed it was getting the second of two values. Try the `zealousl` example. (possibly `for x in m[::-1]` will do it)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I had missed that part of the spec, but nevertheless the correct answer is always given. If any of the distances are the same, the earlier ones will be overwritten by the later ones, since a dictionary can only have one value for a key.

Comment: Oh of course, sweet side-effects Batman :)