# Is the bus load legal?

Tags: code-golf, number, matrix, classification

I was in the bus today, and noticed this sign:

```
      seated    standing    wheelchairs
max1    37         30            00
max2    36         26            01
max3    34         32            00
```

The number of seated passengers, standees, and wheelchairs all have to be no larger than some row in the table. [(See chat for details.)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46040321#46040321)

For the purposes of this challenge we will generalise this idea: Given a non-negative integer list of a strictly positive length N (number of passenger types) and a non-negative integer matrix of strictly positive dimensions (N columns and one row per configuration, or the transpose of this), return a list of indices/truthy-falsies/two-unique-values indicating which configurations limits are fulfilled.

E.g. with the above matrix:
`30,25,1` → `[1]` (0-indexed) `[2]` (1-indexed) or `[false,true,false]` (Boolean) or `["Abe","Bob","Abe"]` (two unique values) etc.

The following test cases use the above matrix and the 0/1 for false/true:
`[30,30,0]` → `[1,0,1]`
`[30,31,0]` → `[0,0,1]`
`[35,30,0]` → `[1,0,0]`
`[0,0,1]` → `[0,1,0]`
`[0,0,0]` → `[1,1,1]`
`[1,2,3]` → `[0,0,0]`

The following test cases use the following matrix:
`1 2 0 4`
`2 3 0 2`

`[1,2,1,2]` → `[0,0]`
`[1,3,0,1]` → `[0,1]`
`[1,2,0,3]` → `[1,0]`
`[1,2,0,1]` → `[1,1]`

Comment: Am I misunderstanding this challenge or can `[30,31,0]` be `[1, 1, 1]` because it's covered by `max3`?

Comment: Is swapping truth values allowed? (e.g. any truthy value in place of `0` and any falsy one in place of `1`?)

Comment: @Okx You're misunderstanding something. `[x,31,z]` rules out `max1` and `max2` because they don't allow 31 standees.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Is that usually allowed in challenges like this?

Comment: I [used to think (see *(2)*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156522#comment381430_156522) (also see [Martin's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156522#comment381450_156522)) this is allowed by default, but I haven't found a meta consensus. I have proceeded by [posting this meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16064/is-consistently-swapping-truthy-falsy-values-allowed-in-decision-problems), whose conclusion that the OP should be asked first. I usually allow it, I don't see the reason why they shouldn't be swapped.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I think I'll leave it like this for now (several answers are already in), but I'll try to keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder To my understanding: If you are using the same truthy value / falsy value (always use `1` for thuthy, `0` for falsy), they are "two unique values" which is allowed by this post; If your truthy value / falsy value variance between testcases (sometime use `0` for falsy, but sometime use `false` for falsy), they are not allowed.

Comment: @tsh Right, that's correct with the current formulation of the OP.

Comment: I think Okx's misunderstanding could be avoided if the example matrix wasn't square.

Comment: @JiK Right. That's why I included the other test matrix as well.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <strike>5</strike> 3 bytes

```
∧.≤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHcv1HnUu@f/f2EABiAyAYhM1jM0VjM0UjE00NYBCRkCWkaaGgYKhgoEmF1CJgiEhRYYKRgrGxCgCYrAyIK2pAdQDkjTQ1DABcsHyBlBjsMkDAA)

Comment: [`∧.≤`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHcv1HnUu@f/f2EABiAyAYhM1jM0VjM0UjE00NYBCRkCWkaaGgYKhgoEmF1CJgiEhRYYKRgrGxCgCYrAyIK2pAdQDkjTQ1DABcsHyBlBjsMkDAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks @Adám. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: It looks like emoji.  `^_^` `>,<` `@.@`

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
map.(or.).zipWith(>)
```

Returns `False` if legal and `True` if not.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYs7DsIwEER7TrEFRSINlu2NQgXXoDAurICJRT5WkorDYxY6upn3ZvqwPu/DUCKd6FrGkFU1L6pWr5Qvaeurcy0wTWJv844oL2naaE@RHGuwgfbkHB8hTXs4bmFbmG9qwFaY/38ZMLQM5GUgHo1s7Q9a78u7i0N4rOXQ5fwB)

Flipping True/False as return values saves 2 bytes (thanks @user202729!). With `True` for legal it's `map.(and.).zipWith(<=)` (22 bytes). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYsxDsIwEAR7XnEFRSIdlu2LQkPeQWGusBJMLBxjkVQ8HnPQ0e3O7M5@vV9TqgEGuNTFF9X4PKlWvWI5x21uTkMrOGbx02MHUJ4xb7CHAI40kkHN4BwdUZpmdNSj7dF8U4dkhfH/yyChloG8DIrHTrb2By1zfY8h@dtaD2MpHw)

Comment: Flipping true and false in the output results in a shorter solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 15 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b)all(a>=b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@9CsIwFIX3PEXAwQTucH@qDqHiC/QJSoZUOwhFhRbBp48pQls1HUIyfOfLOffzEJ5tjCcToLGh60w4lo2NQ9sPutTh1itVUXrVcgBBQCd74D2QkwKEAf1WXa79owsvM2ZMRVBLotCht1ZvdE2AQD5P0UThGrX7dWGGSoSjyUSrzOyh7G/k2MmiUfKoisf5BGksFI5B0s1/s/kTTmeO@xwj31V93oNTDVrx8MIzjtHxDQ)

As per sundar's comment, omitting the transpose saves 2 bytes.

Comment: OP allows taking the matrix as the transpose of what's shown in the question, and you can take `b` as a column vector instead of a row vector (since it's just specified as a list), saving 2 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@9CsIwFIX3PEXAwQTucH@qDqHiC/QJSoZUOwhFhRbBp48pQls1HUIyfOfLOffzEJ5tjCcToLGh60w4lo2NQ9sPutTh1itVUXrVcgBBQCd74D2QkwKEAf1WXa79owsvM2ZMRVBLotCht1ZvdE2AQD5P0UThGrX7dWGGSoSjyUSrzOyh7G/k2MmiUfKoisf5BGksFI5B0s1/s/kTTmeO@xwj31V93oNTDVrx8MIzjtHxDQ "Octave – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
<Ẹ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/m4a4dj5rW/P//Pzra2FxHwdhAR0HBIFaHSyHa2ExHwQiIFQwhXBOgrBFYNvZ/tLEpRK1BLAA)

`0` = True, `1` = False.

Comment: If the values needn't be distinct, `<§` would work

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I don't think that option is given here. I guess I'll wait and see.

Comment: [It is allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170005/is-the-bus-load-legal?noredirect=1#comment410625_170005).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Hm, it looks like `<§` isn't exactly "truthy-falsy" but rather "falsy-truthy", which, unfortunately, isn't what the challenge asks for.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Jelly needs `≥`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
>Σy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/3@7c4sr//6ONDXQUQNgglis62tgcwgHydBSijc10FIyA2BDMMQFKGYGlYgE)

Algorithm: vectorized `>` (greater than), `Σ` sum each, `y` sign.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
<~A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYy7DYBADEN7psgI@SAoTIPECHQnJOiho2b1kENXwlFEsexnH9u5@@rDNfo0e7KerCNrYUwaQsEkxEuTjMPDo6qM/DCxAakSAoXlTwolC5/RkpYk7iOzsvze48pm7t0)

Takes the input matrix as a transpose of the format in the question (as allowed by OP), with one column per configuration. Outputs boolean 0 and 1 for false and true.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 26 bytes

```r
function(x,y)!colSums(x<y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY49CsMwDIX33KKbBW@QLTddmlP0BMVgCDQJpAk4p3fkdqjdQYhP7wetOQ457nPYxmU2CQddwvJ67NPbpPtBOQ3Tc1vHZIKRG4TBkB6uh4V4iAMThLqoUXXwx0E125qvrV7abEM/zcJpMXXVA@XE8EXQ7Qi@NutUYWmqv0n5Y9XzCQ)

Accepts the matrix in transposed form as `x`, test config as `y`. Returns a vector of booleans.

Initial -2 bytes thanks to mnel, and further -4 by JayCe.

Comment: Save 2 bytes with a function body apply(x>=y,2,all)

Comment: [save 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY49CsMwDIX33KKbBW@QLTddmlP0BMVgCDQJpAk4p3fkdqjdQYhP7wetOQ457nPYxmU2CQddwvJ67NPbpPtBOQ3Tc1vHZIKRG4TBkB6uh4V4iAMThLqoUXXwx0E125qvrV7abEM/zcJpMXXVA@XE8EXQ7Qi@NutUYWmqv0n5Y9XzCQ)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Takes input as `(matrix)(vector)`. Returns a Boolean array.

```javascript
m=>v=>m.map(r=>!r.some((t,x)=>v[x]>t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBbsIwDIbveQrvlkhesRu2HVD6BjxBlEMFZdpECWorxNsXQwWpRCMlhzifftvff32p@133dx4@T3HfjAc3tq66uKot2vqsO1d9dEUf20brAa9Gvvw1VIMx4xYceAXgwf4gWEIggoBT5RuhlEv8qqyFKSdGhY3axVMfj01xjL/6oLdGe0mQQ8EYWK3AMxJyyHCcOMpyX295tMRNAQCvPM5zlDgWbrEvY4l2nvfW12yUSvZYVIkXhPXTlTzto1LmXN17yJ05WJ7EPnZLm@XmFaUzT3mKE8VhvAE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*-1 bytes from @Shaggy*

```
eÈ¨Vv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P/Vwx6EVYWX//0dHG5vrKBgb6CgoGMTqcClEG5vpKBgBsYIhhGsClDUCy8YqcHFFG5vqABUbxCro5v7/DwA)

Comment: `VgY` -> `Vv` to save a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
map.((.).(==)<*>(zipWith min))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzexQE9DQ09TT8PWVtNGy06jKrMgPLMkQyE3M09TEyidmadgq1BQWhJcUqSgp1CckV@uoKKQphBtbKADRAaxCtHRxuYQpg5Q1EzHyEzHEMw00TE2AorG/v@XnJaTmF78Xze5oAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 57 bytes

```
\d+
$*
;(?=.*;(.*))
;$1¶
%(+`,1*(1*)(;.*),\1$
$2
(1*);\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYqxDYAwDAR7zxEkx1gRDnQWomSJFCBBQUOBmI0BWMwkNVC87v/0x3pu@2wVjpOlpQZHoDj0gRQDeQ/q5L6gwnpiIRTyqNlzEgcuQhGau5lw5IY7jdxmRi07B96@UODr33D74@UB) Link includes test cases, but the output is all run together. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
;(?=.*;(.*))
;$1¶
```

Give each row of the matrix its own copy of the list.

```
%(
```

Operate separately on each row of the matrix.

```
+`,1*(1*)(;.*),\1$
$2
```

Repeatedly remove the last number of the row and list while the last number of the row is at least as big as that of the list.

```
(1*);\1$
```

There should then be one number left in the list and the number in the row should be at least as big as that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda m,l:[l==map(min,l,r)for r in m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCsMgFAX3OcVfJvAWUdsUAp7EurAUqeA3Itnk9FbTktUbhjf52D9bktXrZ42OX29HjLiaqDW7PHJIiCiT3woVConYVhakyRj1gJoxW5BRC@QCceINSjZrh57Enph2u54NxR/vl23zqzucRkBC2XUgyiWknfzIAhSn@gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εs<›P
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3NZim0cNuwL@/4@ONjbXMTbQMYjViTY20zEy0zEEsUx0jI2AYrFc0UA5I1OgIAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9o6Obp6WKvpPCobZKCkv2hlcX/z209tM7mUcOugP@1Ov@jo43NdYwNdAxidaKNzXSMzHQMQSwTHWMjoFgsVzRQzsgUKMhFjEqwNHEqDYlTaUqsmUApolwJUkeMeYY6RjrGIHUghoGOCVAWKABkGcFkgRiPvDHMPTj1GxAwH6QfAA).

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately 05AB1E v1 doesn't have a 1-char builtin for `≤` or `≥`, so I decrease each value instead before using `›`. [05AB1E v2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46036557#46036557) which is currently in development will have these builtins.

```python
ε        # For-each row of the (implicitly input) matrix:
 s       #  Swap, so the (implicitly input) list is at the top of the stack
  <      #  Decrease every value in the input-list by 1
         #   i.e. [30,25,1] → [29,24,0]
   ›     #  Check for each value in the matrix-row if they're larger
         #  than the input-list value at the same index
         #   i.e. [37,30,0] and [29,24,0] → [1,1,0]
    P    #  Then take the product of these checks
         #   i.e. [1,1,0] → 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â ╤┘µrφî
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8320d1d9e672ed8c&i=[30,+30,+0],+[[37,+30,+0],+[36,+26,+1],+[34,+32,+0]]%0A[30,+31,+0],+[[37,+30,+0],+[36,+26,+1],+[34,+32,+0]]%0A[35,+30,+0],+[[37,+30,+0],+[36,+26,+1],+[34,+32,+0]]%0A[0,+0,+1],+[[37,+30,+0],+[36,+26,+1],+[34,+32,+0]]%0A[0,+0,+0],+[[37,+30,+0],+[36,+26,+1],+[34,+32,+0]]%0A[1,+2,+3],+[[37,+30,+0],+[36,+26,+1],+[34,+32,+0]]%0A[1,+2,+1,+2],+[[1,+2,+0,+4],+[2,+3,+0,+2]]%0A[1,+3,+0,+1],+[[1,+2,+0,+4],+[2,+3,+0,+2]]%0A[1,+2,+0,+3],+[[1,+2,+0,+4],+[2,+3,+0,+2]]%0A[1,+2,+0,+1],+[[1,+2,+0,+4],+[2,+3,+0,+2]]&a=1&m=2)

Explanation:

```
mx\{:vm|A Full program, unpacked, implicit input
m         Map over rows of the matrix:
 x\         Zip with input array
   {  m     Map over result:
    :v        Check if non-increasing, i.e. matrix element greater than or equal to array element
       |A   All.
            Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
zzᵐ{≥₁ᵐ∧1|∧0}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv6oKSFY/6lz6qKkRyHrUsdywBkgYgCX/RytER0cb6hjpGOiYxOpEG@kYA1lGsbE6CiBhBWMdBQMdBcNYiAAehUaoCo3NFYwNFAxAHGMzBSMzoAyIaaJgbAQUBasxNtAxNtQxIE2HEUSHQiwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
Inner[Less,##,Or]&
```

Returns a list of two unique values: `True` means falsy, `False` means truthy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY69CoNAEIR7n2LhwGoC92NMFbENBJL@uEKCEgstTrvjnv2yWggpEnSr2ZmP2R2a@d0Ozdy/mtTRNd3GsfX23k4ThMDDuzw9fT/ONggR6VRRZ4VwjnKq6zqjwGMuMBIyIpgSuoRaVAGj2YugwOGaR2REO3l1hD8f6@eMvSP0/m4FDbPRyyZRMMMuK70xatX/KfP15@8uuevi2hXTBw)