# Edit distance where a substitution only costs the first time

Tags: fastest-algorithm, edit-distance

This challenge is about the following variant of [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965.).  Say we have a cost of 1 for inserts, deletes and substitutions as usual with one exception. A substitution for a given letter `x` for a letter `y` only costs `1` the first time.  Any further substitutions of `x` for `y` cost 0.

As simple examples:

```
A = apppple
B = attttle
```

cost 1 (not 4) to transform A into B. This is because we change `p` for a `t` four times but we only charge for the first one.

```
A = apxpxple
B = atxyxtle
```

cost 2 (not 3) as the `p` to `t` substitution only costs 1 even though we do it twice.

```
A = apppple
B = altttte
```

cost 3. `p` -> `l` costs 1. `p` -> `t` costs 1 as does `l` -> `t`.

If we assume the total length of the input is `n`, you must give the big O() of your algorithm. The best time complexity wins.

---

We should assume the alphabet size can be as large as `n`.

Comment: I think this really is a duplicate of the [original Levenshtein distance challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67474/levenshtein-distance). The only difference is that this challenge requires the fastest code rather than the shortest.

Comment: @SunnyMoon It isn't because it's a different distance function.  The important twist is "A substitution for a given letter x for a letter y only costs 1 the first time. "

Comment: Are we _only_ dealing with substitutions here? Or are insertions & deletions allowed?

Comment: If we can assume that there are only 26 possible letters (or some constant), it seems one can "cheat" the time complexity by iterating over all possible sets of letter-to-letter replacements that are used. There are an astronomical number of these, but it's a constant independent of the length of the input so doesn't affect the algorithm's big-O.

Comment: @Shaggy insertion and deletions are allowed. The cost is 1 per insert/delete.

Comment: @xnor I will edit the question. We should assume the alphabet can be as large as `n`.

Comment: @SunnyMoon Note that being a dupe on Code Golf requires that a serious solution to one challenge is expected to be a serious contender (with minor changes) to the other. Even if the task is 100% identical, a [tag:code-golf] and a [tag:fastest-algorithm] are not likely to be dupes, unless the shortest algorithm is also the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

## Naive recursive algorithm \$ O(\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n}{\sqrt{n}}) \$

The basic idea is try adding, removing and replacing one character and recursive.

```python
def f(str1, str2):
  l1, l2 = len(str1), len(str2)
  mapping = set()
  def g(p1, p2):
    if l1 == p1 or l2 == p2:
      return l1 + l2 - p1 - p2
    cost1 = g(p1 + 1, p2) + 1
    cost2 = g(p1, p2 + 1) + 1
    if str1[p1] != str2[p2] and (str1[p1], str2[p2]) not in mapping:
      mapping.add((str1[p1], str2[p2]))
      cost3 = g(p1 + 1, p2 + 1) + 1
      mapping.discard((str1[p1], str2[p2]))
    else:
      cost3 = g(p1 + 1, p2 + 1)
    return min(cost1, cost2, cost3)
  return g(0, 0)
```

The function `g` will be invoked \$ O(\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n}{\sqrt{n}}) \$ times<sup>[1]</sup>. While adding, discarding, or checking an element in the mapping cost \$ O(1) \$ on average.

[1]: Based on https://oeis.org/A027618 ; I don't know why actually...

Comment: `(str1[0], str2[0]) not in mapping` takes \$O(1)\$ (a `set` is a hash table), but `mapping | {(str1[0], str2[0])})` takes \$O(n)\$ (it constructs a new `set`), as do `str1[1:]` and `str2[1:]` (they construct a new `str`). But [A001850](http://oeis.org/A001850)(n/2) is \$O{\left(\frac{(1 + \sqrt 2)^n}{\sqrt n}\right)}\$, so you can take off a \$\sqrt n\$ factor from the number of invocations.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg str1[1:] can be replaced by passing another variable `pos1`; `mapping | {...}` can be replaced by `mapping |= {...}` The O(n) is not necessary.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Sorry but I didn't find the formula \$ \frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \$ in the page you linked. And also cannot get it by myself. Could you tell me more about where I can find this formula?

Comment: It follows from Hirschhorn’s comment (and [proof](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper68.ps)), with [Stirling’s approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442351/stirling-approximation-of-binom2nn) for \$\binom{2n}{n}\$.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Let \$ g(x) = (1+\sqrt2)^x \$. We have \$ 2g(x-1)+g(x-2) = g(x) \$. But I'm not sure if \$O((1+\sqrt2)^n)\$ is correct to describe time complexity. Because time used should be \$ f(n) = 2f(n-1)+f(n-2)+1 \$. But this at least prove \$ f(n) = \Omega((1+\sqrt2)^n) \$. So I'm not sure how \$ O(\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n}{\sqrt{n}}) \$ comes.

Comment: Since every non-leaf node in the call tree has degree three, just over 2/3 of the nodes are leaves, so it suffices just to count those. (Or see [A027618](https://oeis.org/A027618).) Your argument for \$\Omega((1 + \sqrt 2)^n)\$ pessimistically assumes that the recursion terminates at `p1 + p2 == l1 + l2`, while it actually terminates at `p1 == l1 or p2 == l2`.

Comment: Thank you for giving the first answer!

Comment: Bounty awarded as you have the best time complexity. I would still love to see any new algorithms/analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Wagner–Fischer algorithm, each cell (here I just store a single row rather than the whole matrix) contains a list of tuples of edit distances and their associated transpositions. The matrix itself requires \$ O(n^2) \$ to traverse, but I don't know the cost of tracking the sets of transpositions, which varies across the grid roughly in line with Delannoy numbers. The code also merges distances with the same transpositions; I don't know whether that increases or reduces the complexity.

```python
def dist(fr, to):
  costs = [[(i, frozenset())] for i in range(len(fr) + 1)]
  for j in range(len(to)):
    editcosts = costs[0]
    delcosts = costs[0] = [(costs[0][0][0] + 1, frozenset())]
    for i in range(len(fr)):
      inscosts = costs[i + 1]
      allcosts = [(c + 1, s) for c, s in delcosts + inscosts] + [(c, s) if fr[i] == to[j] or fr[i] + to[j] in s else (c + 1, s | {fr[i] + to[j]}) for c, s in editcosts]
      allcosts = [min((c, s) for c, s in allcosts if s == e) for e in {s for c, s in allcosts}]
      costs[i + 1] = allcosts
      editcosts = inscosts
      delcosts = allcosts
  return min(costs.pop())

print(dist("apxpxple", "atxyxtle"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbaoQwEH33Kw4@JbiUlr4V9kvEB1nHNotNJEnB7Xa/3U5iDLqIgsmcORdmHG/@y@j3ee6oR6ecF709wRv5UQAX47zDGXUt1Am9Nb@kHXkhZYPeWCgoDdvqTxIDaWZKVHiTDVMDfN3DLBpVAeqUX7Xjt35tItDR8FwP9mK9LG8weYoT2ceRkicYcHtxFYSahLZDtma/xcLJqHnhU5DN6aqsFbJwe2xVPWeqFSc@8wDrawPmLpUqFVjEgQZHyBb4w33X9Nib5lkdBf1WWiT3LSe3cCQX4tCCUwDv7rD3sepvZ8MeK57Q7erWISRos7wNyZL/sRohaSy9jGbkjRXFaJX2Iv5yZTtO/AxUnlC2frpNns9SzvM/)

Comment: I'll try to run an experiment with larger inputs to see what the running time might be. Unless someone can analyse this answer?

Comment: @Anush if no distances have the same transpositions (which for an alphabet of size n is not far from average case of 1), then for each cell (i,j) from the Wagner-Fischer algorithm, this forms a list with one tuple `(c,s)` for every path from (0,0) to (i,j). The number of paths are the Delannoy numbers D(i,j), so the total would be \$O(\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n D(m,n))\$. http://ias.sabanciuniv.edu/documents/kiselmanpaper.pdf proves that \$3^{min(i,j)}\leq D(i,j)\leq(\sqrt{2}+1)^{i+j}\$. Summing those across (i,j), we can show that the algorithm is \$O((\sqrt{2}+1)^{2n})\$ and \$\Omega(3^n)\$

Comment: The main two differences between this answer and tsh's "Naive recursive algorithm" is that (1) Wagner-Fischer proceeds forward from (0,0) rather than backwards from (n,n), and (2) this answer generates a list in O(D(i,j)) for each cell rather than having O(D(n,n)) total runtime

Comment: Maybe rewrite the two lines about `allcosts` may reduce complexity. But I'm not sure since I actually didn't understand what happened there.

Comment: The time complexity may be \$ O(e^{1.2n}) \$ ~ \$ O(e^{1.4n}) \$. [Guessed based on first few values](https://tio.run/##dVLLboMwELzzFXuLXTgkTV@JxJcgDhSWZCNiIts9tGm@na4NRoCohIS9452Zfdy@7blV@66rsIaKjBW1TsC28hgBWLoipLDlY9kaa/icZYISqHX7g8qgFVLmULcaCEiBLtQJRYOKSSTEsJM5pzr4MoeZ3wsAYEU2cPt/ts09UGGzjDt5ES7950QWdnz2uqVBExgwc3JyRPmAFs0ozXq9hJGes@STox3dxSOX88LP/VOq2VNG7DjlXmaXHDi3j8RDgEkMYGMQRgn4hfvs0WMuOvYqGPXziVNw5QXTEp78/W5muQF@yJUir6TE4Hwtx5VjXCnY4@jA//iDt2lfWSPgAzode2jgAE0GP0nSaL@08hVH0WK6Bz/XmyZlhRPkBfWbvCk@S17r05k22ZHyBDa75/3L69v7x8EHpIyirvsD)

Comment: @tsh Not sure what you're trying to measure there, I create one list and some sets in that loop, so that would be `len(allcosts) + sum(len(s) for c, s in editcosts)`?

Comment: @Neil I'm trying to measure the statement `[min((c, s) for c, s in allcosts if s == e) for e in {s for c, s in allcosts}]`; `for e in {s for c, s in allcosts}` iterate `len({s for c, s in allcosts})` times while `for c, s in allcosts` iterate `len(allcosts)` times. And the two nested loop cost `len(allcosts) * len({s for c, s in allcosts})` times. Maybe I misread the Python code?

Comment: @tsh I suspected that line of code might have a negative effect on the complexity measurement. As it's not actually required for proper functioning of the program, should I remove it?

Comment: Can this analysis be improved before the bounty runs out?

Answer (score 2):

A* Search, unknown complexity. Seems to at least achieve \$o(2^{n})\$ and is quite fast in practice. No reason to think it's optimal, but making it better seemed like too much work.

```
import collections
import heapq

def dist(s0, s1):
    l0, l1 = len(s0), len(s1)
    suffix_sets = tuple([frozenset(s[i:]) for i in range(len(s) + 1)] for s in (s0, s1))
    q = []
    def push_node(g, i, j, substs):
        suff0, suff1 = suffix_sets[0][i], suffix_sets[1][j]
        substs = frozenset(
            t for t in substs if t[0] in suff0 and t[1] in suff1
        )
        substs0, substs1 = {c0 for c0, _ in substs}, {c1 for _, c1 in substs}
        h0 = abs((l0 - i) - (l1 - j))
        h1 = max(len((suff0 - suff1) - substs0), len((suff1 - suff0) - substs1))
        h = max(h0, h1)
        heapq.heappush(q, (g + h, -g, -len(substs), i, j, substs))
    closed = collections.defaultdict(lambda: set())
    push_node(0, 0, 0, frozenset())
    while True:
        (f, neg_g, _, i, j, substs) = heapq.heappop(q)
        g = -neg_g
        if (i == l0) or (j == l1):
            return f
        closed_ij = closed[(i, j)]
        if (g, substs) in closed_ij:
            continue
        subsumed = False
        for (g1, substs1) in closed_ij:
            if g1 <= g and substs.issubset(substs1):
                subsumed = True
                break
        if subsumed:
            continue
        if substs:
            closed_ij.add((g, substs))
        c0, c1 = s0[i], s1[j]
        if (c0 == c1) or ((c0, c1) in substs):
            push_node(g, i + 1, j + 1, substs)
            continue
        push_node(g + 1, i + 1, j, substs)
        push_node(g + 1, i, j + 1, substs)
        push_node(g + 1, i + 1, j + 1, substs | frozenset([(c0, c1)]))
```

Comment: I also have a version which uses a Trie for the subsumption testing, and is a bit faster.

Comment: Please add another answer with the trie version too!

Comment: And how might this be improved?

Comment: @Anush The most obvious way would be to improve the heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

I worked a bit more on this, against my better judgement :). A* search, more complicated than my other answer.

```
import collections
import heapq
import itertools

class SubsumptionTrie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.max_len = 0
        self.min_v = float('inf')
        self.children = {}
    def insert(self, k, v, i=0):
        self.max_len = max(self.max_len, len(k) - i)
        self.min_v = min(self.min_v, v)
        if i >= len(k):
            return
        c = k[i]
        if c not in self.children:
            self.children[c] = SubsumptionTrie()
        self.children[c].insert(k, v, i + 1)
    def subsumption_test(self, k, v, i=0):
        if i >= len(k):
            return self.min_v <= v
        if (self.min_v > v) or (self.max_len < (len(k) - i)):
            return False
        c = k[i]
        for b, child in self.children.items():
            if b < c and self.children[b].subsumption_test(k, v, i):
                return True
        if c in self.children:
            return self.children[c].subsumption_test(k, v, i + 1)
        return False

def heuristic(s0, s1, n0, n1, substs):
    substs0 = {a for a, _ in substs} | set(s1.keys())
    substs1 = {b for _, b in substs} | set(s0.keys())
    if n0 > n1:
        s0, s1 = s1, s0
        n0, n1 = n1, n0
        substs0, substs1 = substs1, substs0
    h0 = 0
    m1 = sum(n for c, n in s1.items() if c in substs1)
    for c, n in sorted(s0.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]):
        if (c not in substs0) or (m1 < 0):
            h0 += 1 
        else:
            m1 -= n
    h1 = 0
    for c, n in sorted(s1.items(), key=lambda t: (t[0] in substs1, t[1]), reverse=True):
        n0 -= n
        if n0 < 0:
            excess = min(-n0, n)
            h1 += excess
            n -= excess
        if n and (c not in substs1):
            h1 += 1
    return max(h0, h1)
            
def dist(s0, s1):
    labels = itertools.count()
    relabel = collections.defaultdict(lambda: next(labels))
    s0, s1 = [relabel[c] for c in s0], [relabel[c] for c in s1]
    label_count = next(labels)
    l0, l1 = len(s0), len(s1)
    suffix_counts = tuple([collections.Counter(s[i:]) for i in range(len(s) + 1)] for s in (s0, s1))
    q = []
    def push_node(g, i, j, substs):
        suff0, suff1 = suffix_counts[0][i], suffix_counts[1][j]
        substs = frozenset(
            t for t in substs if t[0] in suff0 and t[1] in suff1
        )
        h = heuristic(suff0, suff1, l0 - i, l1 - j, substs)
        heapq.heappush(q, (g + h, -g, -len(substs), i, j, substs))
    push_node(0, 0, 0, frozenset())
    closed = collections.defaultdict(lambda: SubsumptionTrie())
    while True:
        (f, neg_g, _, i, j, substs) = heapq.heappop(q)
        g = -neg_g
        if (i == l0) or (j == l1):
            return f
        closed_ij = closed[(i, j)]
        k = sorted(a * label_count + b for a, b in substs)
        if closed_ij.subsumption_test(k, g):
            continue
        closed_ij.insert(k, g)
        c0, c1 = s0[i], s1[j]
        if (c0 == c1) or ((c0, c1) in substs):
            push_node(g, i + 1, j + 1, substs)
            continue
        push_node(g + 1, i + 1, j + 1, substs | frozenset(((c0, c1),)))
        push_node(g + 1, i + 1, j, substs)
        push_node(g + 1, i, j + 1, substs)
```

Comment: Can you say anything about its performance?

Comment: @Anush The average case seems to be about O(1.2^n).

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)

Port of [@tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215159/110802)

[run it on Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ccd38baa446cb8a3cec175a4ab67278a)

```rust
use std::cmp;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::time::Instant;

fn f(str1: &str, str2: &str) -> usize {
    let mut mapping = HashSet::new();

    fn g(p1: usize, p2: usize, str1: &str, str2: &str, mapping: &mut HashSet<(char, char)>) -> usize {
        let l1 = str1.len();
        let l2 = str2.len();

        if l1 == p1 || l2 == p2 {
            return l1 + l2 - p1 - p2;
        }

        let cost1 = g(p1 + 1, p2, str1, str2, mapping) + 1;
        let cost2 = g(p1, p2 + 1, str1, str2, mapping) + 1;

        let c1 = str1.chars().nth(p1).unwrap();
        let c2 = str2.chars().nth(p2).unwrap();

        let cost3 = if c1 != c2 && !mapping.contains(&(c1, c2)) {
            mapping.insert((c1, c2));
            let cost = g(p1 + 1, p2 + 1, str1, str2, mapping) + 1;
            mapping.remove(&(c1, c2));
            cost
        } else {
            g(p1 + 1, p2 + 1, str1, str2, mapping)
        };

        cmp::min(cost1, cmp::min(cost2, cost3))
    }

    g(0, 0, str1, str2, &mut mapping)
}

fn main() {
    let test_cases = [
        ("apppple", "attttle", 1),
        ("apxpxple", "atxyxtle", 2),
        ("apppple", "altttte", 3),
    ];

    for (a, b, expected) in test_cases.iter() {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let result = f(a, b);
        let duration = start.elapsed();
        println!("A: {}, B: {}, Output: {}, Expected: {}", a, b, result, expected);
        println!("Time elapsed: {:?}", duration);
    }
}
```