# Find the closest swap

Tags: code-golf, edit-distance

Take as input two strings \$A\$ and \$B\$.  Output a string \$C\$ that is \$A\$ but with two characters swapped such that the [Levenshtein distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67474) \$d(C,B)\$ is as small as possible.  You must swap two characters and you cannot swap a character with itself, although you may swap two identical characters in different positions.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

Instead of strings you may instead choose to handle lists of positive integers.

### Examples

Here are some examples of inputs and possible outputs along with the Levenshtein distance achieved.

| A | B | C | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `abcd` | `adcb` | `adcb` | 0 |
| `ybgh` | `epmn` | `ygbh` | 4 |
| `slime` | `slime` | `silme` | 2 |
| `yeboc` | `yoqqa` | `yobec` | 3 |
| `unnua` | `muuna` | `uunna` | 2 |
| `oobis` | `oobi` | `oobis` | 1 |
| `yuace` | `yuac` | `yuaec` | 1 |

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
\ā<.ÆεèyRǝ}Σ¹.L}н
```

Inputs in the order \$B,A\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9vc2FiaWX//1zEgTwuw4bOtcOoeVLHnX3Oo8K5Lkx90L3//3lvcXFhCnllYm9j) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWFvaGVCYdW/o850mijd7jt3NYIl6LDKyqDjs@tPbf40Do9n9oLe//r/I@OVkpMSU5S0lFKTEpOUYrViVZKLcjNA/Irk9IzwPzinMzcVKAAhAaJVOYXFiaClKQm5SeDRXJLS/NAIqV5eaWJYJH8/KRMoACIKoZoKk1MBukBUkBTYgE).

`ā<.Æεèy` could alternatively be `` .ā.Æεø` `` for the same byte-count:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9vc2FiaWX//1wuxIEuw4bOtcO4YFLHnX3Oo8K5Lkx90L3//3lvcXFhCnllYm9j) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWFvaGVCYdW/o/RO9Kod7jt3NaI4sM7EoKOz609t/jQOj2f2gt7/@v8j45WSkxJTlLSUUpMSk5RitWJVkotyM0D8iuT0jPA/OKczNxUoACEBolU5hcWJoKUpCblJ4NFcktL80AipXl5pYlgkfz8pEygAIgqhmgqTUwG6QFSQFNiAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
\           # Discard the first (implicit) input `B`
 ā          # Push a list in the range [1, length of second (implicit) input `A`]
  <         # Decrease it to range [0, length_A)
   .Æ       # Get all pairs without duplicates
     ε      # Map over each pair:
      è     #  Index them into the second (implicit) input `A`
       yR   #  Push the pair reversed
         ǝ  #  Insert them into the second (implicit) input `A`
     }Σ     # After the map: sort the strings by:
        .L  #  The Levenshtein distance with
       ¹    #  the first input `B`
      }н    # After the sort: pop and leave the first string
            # (which is output implicitly as result)

 .ā         # Enumerate the second (implicit) input,
            # pairing each character with its index
   .Æ       # Get all pairs without duplicates
     ε      # Map over each pair:
      ø     #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
       `    #  Pop and push the pair of characters and pair of indices separated to
            #  the stack
        R   #  Reverse the indices-pair
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 163 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`, where **a** and **b** are arrays of characters. Returns another array of characters.

This really just tries all possibilities and computes the Levenshtein distance for each of them. It seems very likely that there's a smarter/shorter way.

```javascript
a=>M=b=>a.map((x,i)=>a.map((y,j,[...s])=>j<=i|(s[i]=y,s[j]=x,n=b.length,g=m=>v=m*n?1+Math.min(g(m,--n),g(--m)-(s[m]==b[n++]),g(m)):m+n)(s.length)>M||(M=v,o=s)))&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/BboQgEIDhe5@i8bCBCiS9Nh37BD6B4QDIIkYGt6hZE9/drs2ue1mP/@RjMrRqUsn8@n7gGGu7nmFVUJSgoVAiqJ6QK/N0j5m1rBJCJHmbtd/gF5IqL2FmqWolXBmCFp1FNzTMQYBigvCBP595qYZGBI/EkcA4R8oc4TxQfnsfJICuMM/lNg2UfoUcKUn3RbQol4WUMLEIiVJ6OsXVREyxs6KLjpzJdlGmtKmzd0nvVRu9FX17QWftmie1fcBDmjofbPagj3q91epodjrHy0Ud0RFxVDsN44iHNEbt0063Ov7WqMzz1q3@6foH)

Comment: `m*n?…:m+n` -> `m+n>0&&…` save 1 byte.

Comment: @tsh Would it really work? It would compute an invalid Levenshtein distance in some cases (e.g. [this one](https://tio.run/##lY0xDoJAEEV7jkFhZlx2A63JrJHeExAKQFgwzKxxCddfNVpooYndy8/L@@dmbUJ3nS6LFn/qYxxySgLZliwItWbuxS1j5ojJrsRb2Rfq2Cyj4UnAAWdaC2YOtGbUECquidpKlKofKyPuWAlCeIUwGYpffSU232z@vHjLx85L8HNvZu9gyKEyxqSHtMYnlWV5Z0w@rOKLFW8)).

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 15 bytes

```
ė2ḋƛ∩÷Ṙ¹∇Ȧ;‡⁰꘍∵
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwixJcy4biLxpviiKnDt+G5mMK54oiHyKY74oCh4oGw6piN4oi1IiwiIiwiXCJhYmNkXCIsIFwiYWRjYlwiXG5cInliZ2hcIiwgXCJlcG1uXCJcblwic2xpbWVcIiwgXCJzbGltZVwiXG5cInllYm9jXCIsIFwieW9xcWFcIlxuXCJ1bm51YVwiLCBcIm11dW5hXCJcblwib29iaXNcIiwgXCJvb2JpXCJcblwieXVhY2VcIiwgXCJ5dWFjXCIiXQ==)

`ė2ḋƛ∩÷` could be `ẏ2ḋƛ¹İ` for the same byte count.

```
ė2ḋƛ∩÷Ṙ¹∇Ȧ;‡⁰꘍∵
ė                # Enumerate, make a list [index, x] for each x in the first input.
 2ḋ              # Combinations without replacement of length 2; pairs.
   ƛ             # For each:
    ∩            #  Transpose
     ÷           #  Dump; push both items onto the stack.
      Ṙ          #  Reverse the top pair (the pair of two characters). Call this Y, and the other pair X.
       ¹         #  Push the first input
        ∇        #  Push it under the top two values of the stack, aka c,a,b.
         Ȧ       #  Assign; replace each of the indices in X with the corresponding value in Y.
          ;      # Close map.
           ‡  ∵  # Minimum by:
            ⁰꘍   #  Levenshtein distance with the second input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>130</s> 97 bytes

```
\(A,B,x=combn(seq(a<-utf8ToInt(A)),2,\(i)intToUtf8(`[<-`(a,i,a[rev(i)]))))x[order(adist(x,B))[1]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc87bsMwDAbgWT2Gs1CADNRphwzJkGzdk8kxEEqWEwGRFD9U2Gfp4hboRXqL3qaiXC0_oQ8kwY_Pbv5qdt9haPLNL55hLw5i3ClvpYNet4DbPNrm6N_cAHvOxVqcwXDjhqM_RYBLuc0vgMIILDv9Hq3i8Y2l72rdAdamH2AUB87Loqr-F_00kKFUdSZYhrWSGV8xSvb8FGWS1xuJflhHMl3ljb2S9HdjNdFSROvN3Wq2Tm1aekU4-bbF1OilVuyFMDgXkNCG4BLGdLh0ei9NT0gFWfpgRZoaUKWVVKShAePQYrlknpf8Aw)

Another brute-force solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 216 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(n:=len(a))and min(w(c:=[*a],k%n,k//n)or d(c,[*b])for k in range(n*n)if k%n<k//n)
d=lambda s,t:-~min(d(S:=s[1:],T:=t[1:])-(s[0]==t[0]),d(S,t),d(s,T))if s>""<t else len(s+t)
def w(a,i,j):a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PZHBjtsgEIa1R3gKhFQJUtxNdnuo0NKX6N68PgwYJ2zscRKwIl_6Ir1Eqtpnavs0hXg3l2_mZ35Gw_Dj92FOuxEvPzvz8mtKXfXl758eBtsCA2W1QG16jwKkBGzZEFCchdOmXkGj9h9Q7e_vUY4n1gqn6pVtZJfFngVkJ8CtF7hCGTqWrU9XK23NW_uokq6-l46t-KZNrDe6Uc_apJLISsR63Zis1o1U2aFSCVE9y9IvfuX8KTHfR8_KfPFjyq19x84CVFCvUkMdGgX1a2MKVJHL-_7d3SUfk-Gcg3UtgdbZBWs62-2O-MOAZN7aHflMYx8GT94Y-swHOns7OjKPxyNkWu_II50QJyDDNCGQjMwHOo42RFJIlnRD5wmcJ4UF-eYmT_EpHvqQBH9BLul1tDrdzhKXrKw0lZWWYkOLzH-jnGpDTIDOv9c0ZexwCphEl9dg5c0gbwVeVRWXyyYulyX-Bw)

A very bloated answer which just iterates through all pairs of swaps. The Levenshtein distance is adapted from an answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67474/levenshtein-distance), but slightly shortened.