# Write a Stepping Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

*[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51402/each-step-of-the-levenshtein-distance)*

Your goal, is to write a set of programs, that progresses from one to the other, one character at a time. For example. Given the starting program `abcd` and the ending program `wxyz`, you should have 5 valid programs, with the respective outputs.

```
abcd -> wbcd
wbcd -> wxcd
wxcd -> wxyd
wxyd -> wxyz
wxyz -> wxyz
```

As can be seen, the last program should be a quine.

### Rules

- Your start and end program may be any length, And they may also be different lengths
- Your start and end program must contain entirely unique characters at each position, but may share characters overall.
- Each program should affect a single character at a time, in any order, characters should only be added or removed from the end of the program.
- **None** of your programs need to follow the valid quine rules, they only need to output the correct string.
- [Standard Loopholes Apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

### Scoring

Programs are scored by the length of the start program plus the length of the end program in bytes. In the previous example, `4 + 4 = 8`, so the score is eight. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest programs wins.

### Some Valid Programs

*In languages that hopefully don't exist*

```
abcd -> dbcd -> dccd -> dcbd -> dcba
a -> b
a -> b -> bc -> bcd -> bcde
ab -> aa -> ba
[BLANK PROGRAM] -> a
xyz -> xy -> x -> [BLANK PROGRAM]
```

Comment: If the scoring isn't exactly "length of the code" you should use [tag:code-challenge] instead.

Comment: I'd disagree, as it's just the length of 2 programs. It's still very much so a golfing challenge.

Comment: `BLANK PROGRAM` is zero bytes right (thus disallowed according to your first rule?)

Comment: I knew I was going to condradict myself somewhere, fixed. @StewieGriffin

Comment: Python, 0 + 0 = 0: (empty program) it's both the start and end program

Comment: I feel like maybe this should have been [tag:code-bowling], since the shorter an answer is, the fewer stages it needs to go through before reaching the end program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Retina, Score 1

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/A8EAA)

- The empty program outputs `1`, since the empty input matches the empty string exactly once.
- [`1` outputs `0`](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f8P9/AA), since `1` doesn't match the empty input.
- [`0` outputs `0`](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f4P9/AA), since `0` doesn't match the empty input. Since it outputs itself, it's a quine (as defined in this challenge).

Comment: You'd technically need to use the latest Retina commit, because the version on TIO still prints trailing linefeeds by default.

Comment: And I think the empty program *is* allowed, see the second-to-last example in the challenge.

Comment: @MartinEnder The OP was self-contradictory on this when this answer was posted.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen which is why I've informed Stewie that it's now been clarified and the answer can be updated. :)

Comment: @MartinEnder Yeah but the examples didn't change, only the part contradicting them.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah, fair enough.

Comment: @MartinEnder edited :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), Score 1

```
=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f9v9/AA)

`=` prints top of stack (nothing) without newline.

(empty program) also generates no output.

Boring solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), Score 2

```
/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9f//9/AA)

Niladic `/` pushes `5`, with implicit output, `5` also pushes `5`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), Score 2

```
T
```

**Output:** `0` ([Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VA==&input=))

---

```
0
```

**Output:** `0` ([Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MA==&input=))

---

Any uppercase letter after `T` would also work in the same way.